# Update packages in RStudio doesn't work

Tags: r, rstudio

- R 3.2.1
- RStudio Version 0.99.473
- Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4

Clicking Update Packages results in a pop-up window that says "R Error" and then the error print out in the console:

```
Error in if (substr(cranRep, cranRepLen, cranRepLen) != "/") cranRep <- 
paste(cranRep,  :missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I do have a .Rprofile that I use for start-up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [a little digging into Github](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RRO/issues/15), the answer seems to be specifying the following in the .Rprofile:

```
options(repos=c(CRAN="https://cran.rstudio.com/"))
```

as opposed to

```
options(repos="https://cran.rstudio.com/")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue i.e. missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

R and RStudio Versions

- R Studio 1.0.143
- R 3.4.0

**I solved by editing Rprofile.site. Below are the Steps:**

Step 1:
    Go to C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.0\etc or Location where Rprofile.site is

Step 2:
    Open Rprofile.site. And Edit "Set Cran mirror" to

```
    local({r <- getOption("repos")
    r["CRAN"] <- "https://cran.rstudio.com/"
    options(repos=r)})
```

Step 3:
    Restart RStudio if necessary